# input type file multiple сортировка

Tags: javascript, html5

В отобранном массиве файлы получаются в порядке заданном в окне выбора файлов, а как сделать чтоб порядок был определён порядком выбора юзером (Ctrl+ click мышкой)?

Comment: Не думаю что на текущий момент это реально.

Comment: Был в каком месте?

Comment: @Qwertiy  в процессе выбора ,  который происходит с помощью Ctrl+click мышкой.

Comment: @Вадим, не, так нельзя. Это в самой OC зашито, что файлы отдаются в другом порядке.

Comment: очень жаль, придётся что-то городить, а так было б просто